Construct a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{ Q} $...
This question was asked in my final exam ( now over ) of General Topology and I was not able to make much progress despite thinking a lot. So, I am asking it here in order to learn more.
Let $D$ denote the set of dyadic rationals, i.e. rational numbers of the
form $\frac{k} {2^n}$ for $k \in  \mathbb{Z}$ and $n ∈ N$.
Then show that there exists a homeomorphism
$h: (0, 1) → (0, 1)$ such that $h(\mathbb{Q} ∩ (0, 1)) = D ∩ (0, 1)$.
Attempt: A homeomorphism h would be a bijection and h continuous such that $h^{-1}$ would also be continuous.
I read during the course in a book that $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$  is bijective with $ D\cap (0,1) $. So , during exam I was thinking of proving a bijection between $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1) = D\cap (0,1) $ but I couldn't construct a candidate for the map as the problem occurs on how to adjust the odd prime  occuring in $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1) $ in the range of such a bijection ?
Can you please help?

$\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1) \neq D \cap (0,1)$. For example, $\frac{1}{3} \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$ but $\frac{1}{3} \notin D \cap (0,1)$ I think you meant there is a bijection between them.

@RyanNoonan you are right

This is not really a topological proof. But since both $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0, 1)$ and $D \cap (0, 1)$ are countable dense linearly ordered sets without endpoints, they are order-isomorphic. Any such order isomorphism extends to an order isomorphism from $(0, 1)$ to itself using the least upper bound property. (See, for example, my answer here.) Any such order isomorphism is then a homeomorphism because the usual topology on $(0, 1)$ is the order topology.

A somewhat subtle point here is that the subspace topology on $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$ does agree with the order topology, and similarly for $D$, see eg https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3999440

An additional comment: if I’m not mistaken, an explicit example of such a homeomorphism is given by Minkowski’s question mark function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_question-mark_function

… Why did someone suddenly decide to downvote this? What is the problem with this answer?
